# Create table View which behave or look like as a date picker

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I just want to create my own date picker view, means I want to know 
 what is the logic behind the date picker for its **infinite scrolling** loop.

I am using  `tableview`  for that but I stuck in how I make that table as circular format which scroll in infinite loop.

- how much row I will take for that ?
- how I can append upper data at end of row when table scroll at the end of row?

Please let me know if you have any solution regarding this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You know there is a `UIPickerView` right? And you can customise the data inside it...

Comment: Yes I know there is picket view. But I want just create it by my own for getting knowledge

Answer (score 0):

here is the example you need.
http://bharath2020.in/2012/10/01/uitableview-tricks-part-2-infinite-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel.git)? or `UICollectionView`?